# iPhone 4(S) vs iPad2 computer vision performance problems

Tags: iphone, ipad, opencv, computer-vision

We have this project using OpenCV and at first we developed for iPad2.

Everything ran smooth and an computer vision object recognition iteration was taking a little under 1 second.

So far so good. Now we are testing the app for iPhone on both 4 and 4S. Of course we did our research as the results were stating the iPhone4S performance was almost as fast as the iPad2.

The results of the iPhone 4 are terrible, one iteration takes 15 seconds. In the iPhone 4S on iteration takes 8 seconds.

So with our algorithms: 
iPhone4 is 15x slower than an iPad2
iPhone4S is 7-8x slower than an iPad2

Does anybody know if this is true? Is there something the iPhone is doing differently than the iPad2? Isn't the processor of the same type?

Anybody who can point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Similar processors, different camera's. The iPad's camera has less MP's than the iPhone's one. On the iPhone, make sure you downsize your image to an acceptable size before processing.